# Can react hooks be used to inject components?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, dry

Well consider I have a set of components, these components all have some basic fields. An example may be a pop up that shows in case of an erroneous state.

This leads to something like:

```
function MyComponent(props) {
    const [showErr, setShowErr] = React.useState(false);
    const [errMsg, setErrMsg] = React.useState('');
    return <>
        <...>
        <SomePopup
            open={showErr}
            errMsg={errMsg}
        />
    </>
}
```

While this is trivial the settings might not be in case of more complex interactions with the rest of the component isn't. It's also unnecessary boilerplate and violates DRY.

The states can of course be combined in a custom hook `useError` (or in this trivial case in a single state). However can I also make it so that whenever I declare an object to have `useError`, it also has the component set up?

That way I could prevent erros like "forgetting the popup" and "forgetting to set useError state" - DRY errors.

Comment: Might be better written as an HOC instead of a hook

Comment: Out of curiosity, is your preference for each component to render its own separate popup instance, or would you prefer an implementation that renders one popup instance and shares the dispatchers `setShowErr` and `setErrMsg` among multiple components?

Comment: @PatrickRoberts I'm not certain about my preference myself. On one hand "error state messages" are nice if combined. However on the other hand having each component its own popup instance makes the components work "on themselves", and is hence easier for testing.

Comment: That's fair. I was just going to suggest implementing a context provider for the popup if you would have preferred a shared instance instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of a hook, consider the following higher-order component definition:

```
function withSomePopup(MyComponent) {
  return function MyComponentWithSomePopup(props) {
    const [showErr, setShowErr] = React.useState(false);
    const [errMsg, setErrMsg] = React.useState('');
    const propsWithSomePopup = React.useMemo(() => ({
      ...props,
      setShowErr,
      setErrMsg
    }), [props, setShowErr, setErrMsg]);

    return (
      <>
        <MyComponent {...propsWithSomePopup} />
        <SomePopup open={showErr} errMsg={errMsg} />
      </>
    );
  };
}
```

Then you can wrap your component like this:

```
export default withSomePopup(function MyComponent(props) {
  const { setShowErr, setErrMsg } = props;

  return (
    <...>
  );
});
```

Comment: I'm now a bit wondering though, what is the reason for `useMemo`? `props` changes (object identity) each render anyways right?

Comment: @paul23 not necessarily. Other things besides the reference to `props` changing can trigger re-renders of the component, such as state changes via calls to the dispatchers `setShowErr` and `setErrMsg`, and memoizing the reference to `props` will prevent unnecessary refreshes to `useEffect()`, etc., that are dependent on the `props` passed down to the inner component.

Comment: Usually this optimization results in unobservable improvement to performance, but if any dependency triggers effects such as network requests, memoization is vital.